# Having trouble calling next Action once a users login is validated. ERROR redirected you too many times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, authentication

I need to route to a new view once the login is validated. This is currently not working. My authenticateUser method is working correctly as i can see when debugging, but not sure how to get the redirect to work.

CONTROLLER

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (PCSSession.Current.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Landing", "Start");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AttemptToLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = PCSSession.Current.AuthenticateUser(username, password)
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = "Error occured while trying to login"
            };
        }
    }
```

AJAX IN VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
        $.post("/Login/AttemptToLogin",
            {
                username: $('#Username').val(),
                password: $('#Password').val(),
            },
            function (data) {
                if (data == "true") {
                    $("#loginForm").submit();
                } else {

                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order fix my error of too many redirects, i had to change the redirecttoaction to just return view.

```
        if (PCSSession.Current.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            return View("../Start/Landing");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **[HttpPost]** attribute. There are two things you could do here

1. You can pass your url to client and the call `navigate()`, or `window.location = myurl`

   OR
2. return `Redirect(redirectUrl);`

hope this helps.

Comment: no this did not work. I have even tried making a route and calling RedirectToRoute("routename")

Comment: Updated code. Now getting error redirected you too many times.

Comment: @Ha66y-Day can you please add a screenshot of the error you are seeing?